# Prevent possible duplicates on MongoDb Document Array

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have have a bunch of information that is saved inside an array of a document in MongoDb, the structure is something like this:

```json
{
 "Ticker":"TSLA34",
 "History":[
    {
       "Price":26.36,
       "UpdatedAt":"10/22/2015 10:12:00 AM"
    },
    {
       "Price":26.37,
       "UpdatedAt":"10/22/2015 10:13:00 AM"
    }
 ]
}
```

Im saving the information inside the "History" array, and this information is time based, i need to insert minute by minute.

Sometimes the same minute came to me two or three times in a row. So i need to check if the current minute that i received is already inserted in this array before push into this array and save it in MongoDb, but only if the whole document does not exist, i need to create it and insert the information.

Im using `MongoDb.Driver` in .NET 6 and i build this method to insert the information only if the "UpdatedAt" field is not already saved into the "History" array

```cs
// var item = new Chart("TSLA34", new HistoryEntry(26.36, DateTime.UtcNow))

var filterByTicker = Builders<Chart>.Filter.Eq(g => g.Ticker, item.Ticker);

var filterByDate = Builders<Chart>.Filter.ElemMatch(g => g.History, Builders<HistoryEntry>.Filter.Eq(x => x.UpdatedAt, item.History.First().UpdatedAt));

var filter = filterByTicker & Builders<Chart>.Filter.Not(filterByDate);

var update = Builders<Chart>.Update.Push(asset => asset.History, item.History.First());

var updateOneModel = new UpdateOneModel<Chart>(filter, update) {IsUpsert = true};
```

I need to create the document if it isn't created, but if it is already created i need to verify if this information minute is inserted into the history.

I can do this doing a Find search and check it with Linq before do the Update process, but i was wondering if i can do this more efficiently with MongoDb.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I'm not familiar with .net but one option for you could be to find the equivalent of the `$addToSet` operator. See: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: 1. Please store your time field in proper [date object](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/bson-types/#std-label-document-bson-type-date) instead of strings. 2. Have you tried creating a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/)?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the $addToSetEach works, im going to check this unique index constraint too.

Comment: About the property "UpdatedAt", in my database is date object, the example object in the answer is string because i was thinking it will be simpler, thanks for the tip.